# Сохранение вложенных сущностей с помощью SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Допустим есть класс со свойством того же типа (опишу на C#, но язык описания классов здесь неважен)

```cs
class Exception
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string StackTrace { get; set; }

    public Exception InnerException { get; set; }
}
```

Как видно из приведённого выше кода есть класс исключения и у него может быть вложено исключение и так неограниченно.

Создадим таблицу для того, чтобы хранить эти исключения

```
CREATE TABLE Exceptions
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Message] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    StackTrace NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    InnerExceptionId INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK__Exceptions_Id__Exceptions_InnerExceptionId
        FOREIGN KEY(InnerExceptionId) REFERENCES Exceptions (Id)
);
```

Конечно, я могу написать код, который хоть как-то выполняется: к примеру, можно написать хранимую процедуру, которая принимает аргументом TVP, затем пройтись циклом по строкам TVP и вставлять записи одну за другой в таблицу `Exceptions`.

Но есть ли действительно изящный код SQL, который будет делать вставку исключений с вложениями?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52566125/1548895

Comment: а использование user defined type не вариант?

Comment: @Anatol Вы под UDT имеете ввиду TVP? Напишите, пожалуйста, ответ. Может быть и вариант.

Comment: нет, я имею в виду [пользовательские типы CLR](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/clr-user-defined-types); прямо сейчас не располагаю временем на написание ответа

Comment: к тому же, некоторые шаги, объективно, являются не совсем тривиальными )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге создал хранимую процедуру с TVP и циклы через курсор.

Вот определение табличного параметра (table-valued parameter или TVP):

```
CREATE TYPE ExceptionTableType AS TABLE
(
    [Message] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    StackTrace NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
);
```

Вот моя хранимая процедура с циклом через курсор

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LogException
    @exceptions ExceptionTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cursor CURSOR;

    DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @stackTrace NVARCHAR(MAX);

    DECLARE @innerExceptionId INT = NULL;

    DECLARE @outputTable TABLE (Id INT);

    BEGIN
        SET @cursor = CURSOR FOR
        SELECT [Message], StackTrace
        FROM @exceptions;

        OPEN @cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor
        INTO @message, @stackTrace;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Exceptions
            ([Message], StackTrace, InnerExceptionId)
            OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @outputTable (Id)
            VALUES
            (@message, @stackTrace, @innerExceptionId);

            SELECT @innerExceptionId = Id
            FROM @outputTable;

            FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor
            INTO @message, @stackTrace;
        END;

        CLOSE @cursor;
        DEALLOCATE @cursor;
    END
END
```

Пример вызова хранимой процедуры через SQL:

```
DECLARE @exceptions AS ExceptionTableType;

INSERT INTO @exceptions
([Message], [StackTrace])
VALUES
('My exception', 'Some stack trace here'),
('My inner exception', 'Dummy data'),
('My inner exception 2', 'Dummy data 2');

EXEC LogException @exceptions;
```

Answer (score 5):

- Создайте коллекцию для временного хранения строк. Добавьте уникальный суррогатный ключ, например, `id/rowno`. На основе этого ключа будет строится иерархическая зависимость между отдельными строчками. Значение ключа может каждый раз начинаться с 1, это не имеет особого значения.
- Заполните коллекцию данными.
- Вставьте все строчки в постоянную таблицу `Exceptions` с новым сгенерированным значением `IDENTITY` сохраняя связь со значением суррогатного ключа `id/rowno` из коллекции.
- Конвертируйте ранее созданную иерархическую зависимость на основе суррогатного ключа `id/rowno` из коллекции в зависимости основанные на значениях `IDENTITY`. Обновите таблицу.

Итак, предположим `@original_list` будет входной аргумент. Теперь нужно соединить `src.id` с `dst.id` после вставки - `MERGE` справится с этим лучше всего. Потом останется только сконвертировать старые значения ключей в новые.
Все команды *set-based*, никаких циклов:

```
DECLARE @original_list TABLE (
  surrogate_no int not null,
  msg varchar(100) not null,
  inner_surrogate_no int null
);

insert into @original_list (surrogate_no, msg, inner_surrogate_no)
values
  (1000, 'err 1000', null),
  (1010, 'err 1010->1000', 1000),
  (1020, 'err 1020', null),
  (1030, 'err 1030->1010', 1010)

-- args prepared, starting migration

DECLARE @migration TABLE (
  src_id int not null,
  dst_id int not null
)

merge Exceptions t
using @original_list s
on 1=0 --<< we are not looking for updates
when not matched by target then
  insert (message) 
  values (s.msg)
output s.surrogate_no, inserted.id ---<<< here is the main trick: src.id and matching dst.id
into @migration(src_id, dst_id)
;

-- now all error messages are inserted, but none of them have InnerExceptionId

update e set
  InnerExceptionId = mp.dst_id
from Exceptions e
inner join @migration m  --<< get original surrogate_no 
  on m.dst_id = e.id
inner join @original_list o --<< grab original row
  on o.surrogate_no = m.src_id
inner join @migration mp  --<< locate dst.id for inner_surrogate_no
  on mp.src_id = o.inner_surrogate_no
```

Это общее решение для подобных задач. [Полностью на sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a24bf/4)

Вывод:

```
| Id |        Message | StackTrace | InnerExceptionId |
|----|----------------|------------|------------------|
|  1 |       err 1000 |     (null) |           (null) |
|  2 | err 1010->1000 |     (null) |                1 |
|  3 |       err 1020 |     (null) |           (null) |
|  4 | err 1030->1010 |     (null) |                2 |
```

Вывод дерева зависимостей рекурсивным CTE:

```
|                                        Message | Lvl | id | InnerExceptionID |
|------------------------------------------------|-----|----|------------------|
|                                       err 1000 |   1 |  1 |           (null) |
|                                       err 1020 |   1 |  3 |           (null) |
|                    err 1010->1000>>>(err 1000) |   2 |  2 |                1 |
| err 1030->1010>>>(err 1010->1000>>>(err 1000)) |   3 |  4 |                2 |
```

PS Заметьте, *sqlfiddle* не позволяет выполнить `MERGE` внутри большого скрипта (каждый раз возникала ошибка о недостающем `;`), пришлось переделать @ таблицы в постоянные таблицы, а также выполнять `MERGE` в динамическом SQL. На реальном БД сервере в этом не будет необходимости.

Перевод ответа [originally by @IvanStarostin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566125/inserting-nested-entities-with-autoincrement-using-sql-server/52567105#52567105)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, извините, что не отдал конкурс вам, я случайно не заметил ваш ответ в уведомлениях.

Comment: Ничего страшного. Жалко только, что Духу 25 ушло.